# Graphics3D ignores EdgeForm

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d, style, polygons

Works great:

```
Graphics[{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[AbsoluteThickness[10]], Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 1}}]}]
```

Ignores color and thickness:

```
Graphics3D[{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[AbsoluteThickness[10]], Polygon[IdentityMatrix[3]]}]
```

Any suggestions?

[image]

Comment: this is likely to be related to version /OS. It works as expected in version 9/windows10 and in version 11.3 / wolfram cloud.

Comment: Thickness works well and color can be affected by Lighting so use Lighting -> "Neutral" or ambient.

Comment: In my case (Win7, Mma 11.2) it works. I recall that when I had Mma 11.3 it did not, but I do not remember for sure. I cannot check, since I removed 11.3 and everything works again.

Comment: MacOS 10.13.4
Same output in Mathematica 11.2 and 11.3